# Sending files over ajax (superagent) to a PHP backend (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, superagent

Recently I have been messing around with [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) in a project of mine and got to a road block. I am trying to send files via ajax to my Laravel PHP backend but I can't seem to receive anything on the backend side. I have been using superagents 'attach' method with no success.

Javascript (ES6)

```
createProject(input) {

    Request.post(domain + '/projects')
        .withCredentials()
        .field('project', input.project)
          // Truncated for brevity
        .attach('image', input.image)
        .end(function (err, res) {
          // Do something

        }.bind(this));
}
```

When I check the PHP backends received data I get an array of everything excluding the posted file.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can send a file via `superagent` using it's `send` method.

```js
createProject(input) {

  Request.post(domain + '/projects')
    .withCredentials()
    .query({'project': input.project})
    .send(input.file)
    .end(function (err, res) {
      // Do something

  }.bind(this));
}
```

Please note that `input.file` is a instance of [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File).

Comment: Please review my [updated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748936/how-to-send-files-with-superagent). Even while sending an instance of File, I recieve nothing on my backend.